# Nesting if statements no strings

Tags: java, nested, equation, palindrome

I am doing a Palindrome number sequence. I've got the math set up, but I'm having trouble nesting my if statements only showing one answer.

I've attempted to remove the 'if' from the 'else if' but then java doesn't recognize. The output doesn't provide the "Not 5 digits" and when I enter 5 digits that are a Palindrome it sends an output both True and False instead of just true.  However it works perfect for a false 5 digit number input. Can I have some help on how to nest appropriately is what I'm asking for or an example of a good explanation to help me achieve the results as I've been to quite a few sites, but most are too simple and lack examples to compare.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print ("Enter 5-digit integer value: ");
   int userNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input value: " + "\t" + userNumber);

      //User input incorrect amount of digits
      if (userNumber >= 100000 && userNumber <= 9999) 
      {
      System.out.println("Not 5 digits.");
      }   
         else if(userNumber < 100000 && userNumber > 9999)
             {
            int Number5 = (userNumber/10000) % 10;
            int Number4 = (userNumber/1000) % 10;
            int Number3 = (userNumber /100) % 10;
            int Number2 = (userNumber/10) % 10;
            int Number1 = userNumber % 10;

            //Conditions are met for Palidrome Number
              if(Number1 == Number5 && Number2 == Number4)
                {
                  System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "True");
               }
               //Conditions are not met for Palidrome Number
               else if (Number1 != Number5 || Number2 !=Number4);
                     {
                  System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "False");
                   }     
     }
   }
}
```

The results should show true, false, or not 5 digits

Comment: Here's an extra `;`: `else if (Number1 != Number5 || Number2 !=Number4);`

Comment: The second `if` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print ("Enter 5-digit integer value: ");
   String userNumber = input.next();
    System.out.println("Input value: " + "\t" + userNumber);

      //User input incorrect amount of digits
      if (userNumber.length()!=5) 
      {
      System.out.println("Not 5 digits.");
      }   
         else{
            //Conditions are met for Palidrome Number
              if(new StringBuilder(userNumber).reverse().toString().equals(userNumber))
                {
                  System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "True");
               }
               //Conditions are not met for Palidrome Number
               else
                     {
                  System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "False");
                   }     
     }
   }
}
```

Your 2nd `else if` statement is redundant, and you have an extra semicolon in your last if statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is no number that is `>= 100000` **and** `<= 9999`, this is why you never see **Not 5 digits.**
You must change that condition to:

```
if (userNumber <= 9999 || userNumber > 99999)
```

and change:

```
else if(userNumber < 100000 && userNumber > 9999)
```

to a simple

```
else
```

because if the code reaches the `else` part then `userNumber < 100000 && userNumber > 9999` is always `true`.
The same applies to

```
else if (Number1 != Number5 || Number2 !=Number4);
```

(Note: the `;` at the end is wrong and a source of serious headaches) 
which must be changed to:

```
else
```

This statement:

```
int Number3 = (userNumber / 100) % 10;
```

is redundant as the value of `Number3` is not useful in this case.
So your code should be simplified like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter 5-digit integer value: ");
    int userNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input value: " + "\t" + userNumber);

    if (userNumber <= 9999 || userNumber > 99999) {
        System.out.println("Not 5 digits.");
    }
    else {
        int Number5 = (userNumber / 10000) % 10;
        int Number4 = (userNumber / 1000) % 10;
        int Number2 = (userNumber / 10) % 10;
        int Number1 = userNumber % 10;

        if (Number1 == Number5 && Number2 == Number4) {
            System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Judgement: " + "\t" + "\t" + "False");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for the help. I've been able to finally figure out a few more by being more careful and efficient with my work. For whatever reason, I can't get away with putting 'else' in place of 'else if' on my program. It might be the source I'm using it on that won't let me get away with it or more likely, because I'm very new at this. Thank you again!